# put a string in the beginning of a file, + a 3 digit incremental value

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing

I want to put a string in the beginning of a file, + a 3 digit incremental value.

Like this,

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
...
```

to

```
string001 ABC
string002 DEF
string003 GHI
...........
```

so on and so forth.

Thankyou.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to U&L!  What have you tried?  How did its results differ from expectations?

Comment: I am not getting the right way to do this in my head

Comment: File contents or file names?

Comment: Your example prefixes a string, a three digit incrementing number, and a space. But you don't mention the space in the text. Should it be there too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -n -i -e 'printf "string%03d %s", $., $_' file
```

Would edit the `file` `i`n-place and prepend `string` followed by the line number (`$.`) `0`-padded to a width of `3` followed by a single space to each line.

Same with GNU `awk`:

```
gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '{printf "string%03d %s", NR, $0 RT}' file
```

Both can edit more than a file at a time, but to reset the numeric prefix between each file, you need to add `;close ARGV if eof` to the `perl` code and replace `NR` with `FNR` in the `gawk` code.

In `gawk`, **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat -n my_file | sed 's/^/string/g' | tr -s " "
```

Comment: Only works (at giving you 3 digit numbers) for lines with fewer than 10 lines though.